# Can't use struct after its partially moved by closure

Tags: rust, closures, ownership, rust-crates

I'm trying to code a wrapper struct around the creation of an `event_loop` and a graphical context:

```rust
struct GraphicalContext {
    pub el: crow::glutin::event_loop::EventLoop<()>,
    pub ctx: crow::Context
}

impl GraphicalContext {
    pub fn new(wb: WindowBuilder) -> Result<GraphicalContext, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let el = EventLoop::new();
        let ctx = Context::new(wb, &el)?;
        Ok( GraphicalContext { el, ctx } )
    }
}

fn main() {
    let window_bld = crow::glutin::window::WindowBuilder::new();
    let mut gc = GraphicalContext::new(window_bld).unwrap();
    let mut screen_texture: Option<crow::Texture> = None;
    gc.el.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
        match event {
            ...
            Event::RedrawRequested(..) => {
                Some(t) => {
                    let mut surface = gc.ctx.surface();
                    gc.ctx.draw(&mut surface, &t, (0, 0), &DrawConfig::default());
                    gc.ctx.present(surface).unwrap(); // swap back-buffer
                },
                None => ()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Problem is that the compiler complains that `gc` has been partially moved when `gc.el.run()` is called. It tells me it's because `run()` takes ownership of `self` but in this case, `self` is just `gc.el`, but I can't use `gc.ctx` inside the closure. At first I thought it was because the closure used `move`, however, removing it didn't fix the problem and gave me another error. Is there any way I can go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to destructure your structure to get its parts, so that you can move only one of them to the closure:

```
let GraphicalContext { el, ctx } = gc;
el.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
    // use ctx
});
```

Comment: @SandWoodJones You can learn more about this use of pattern matching here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-to-break-apart-values

Comment: The original code might be accepted by the compiler in [edition 2021](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/05/11/edition-2021.html#disjoint-capture-in-closures).

Comment: @user4815162342 Your comment might be a new answer for future viewers